<tree> error in Odoo when creating a Model
I'm new at developing with Odoo and Python, I'm trying to create a module that uses a table of my database and shows the tables in views, this is what I have:
# models.py
from odoo import models, fields

class pc_clientess(models.Model):
    _name = "clientes.pc_clientes"
    _description = "Tabla de clientes"
    _table = "pc_clientes"

    xempgen_id = fields.Char(string="Empresa ID", required=True)
    xcliente_id = fields.Char(string="Cliente ID", required=True)

And:
<odoo>
    <data>

      <record id="clientes_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">clientes.tree.view</field>
        <field name="model">clientes.pc_clientess</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
          <tree>
            <field name="xempgen_id"/>
            <field name="xcliente_id"/>
          </tree>
        </field>
      </record>

      <record id="clientes_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">clientes.form.view</field>
        <field name="model">clientes.pc_clientess</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
          <form>
            <field name="xempgen_id"/>
            <field name="xcliente_id"/>
          </form>
        </field>
      </record>

      <record id="clientes_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Clientes</field>
        <field name="res_model">clientes.pc_clientess</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
      </record>

      <menuitem id="menu_root" name="Rioma"/>
      <menuitem id="menu_clientes" name="Clientes" parent="menu_root"/>
      <menuitem id="menu_clientes_list" name="Clientes List"
      parent="menu_clientes" action="clientes_action"/>
      
    </data>
</odoo>

But when i Activate my module on Odoo, it brings me back this error:
RPC_ERROR

Odoo Server Error

Occured on localhost:8069 on model ir.module.module and id 16 on 2024-11-19 08:40:10 GMT

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\odoo\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 537, in _tag_root
    f(rec)
  File "C:\odoo\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 437, in _tag_record
    record = model._load_records([data], self.mode == 'update')
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\odoo\odoo\models.py", line 5446, in _load_records
    records = self._load_records_create([data['values'] for data in to_create])
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\odoo\odoo\models.py", line 5350, in _load_records_create
    records = self.create(vals_list)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<decorator-gen-138>", line 2, in create
  File "C:\odoo\odoo\api.py", line 480, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\odoo\addons\website\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 64, in create
    return super().create(vals_list)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<decorator-gen-9>", line 2, in create
  File "C:\odoo\odoo\api.py", line 480, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 516, in create
    result = super(View, self.with_context(ir_ui_view_partial_validation=True)).create(vals_list)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<decorator-gen-0>", line 2, in create
  File "C:\odoo\odoo\api.py", line 480, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\odoo\odoo\models.py", line 4954, in create
    records = self._create(data_list)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\odoo\odoo\models.py", line 5121, in _create
    row.append(field.convert_to_column_insert(stored[fname], self, stored))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\odoo\odoo\fields.py", line 982, in convert_to_column_insert
    value = self.convert_to_column(value, record, values, validate)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\odoo\odoo\fields.py", line 2925, in convert_to_column
    value = self.convert_to_cache(value, record)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\odoo\odoo\fields.py", line 2935, in convert_to_cache
    raise ValueError("Wrong value for %s: %r" % (self, value))
ValueError: Wrong value for ir.ui.view.type: 'tree'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 1954, in _transactioning
    return service_model.retrying(func, env=self.env)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\odoo\odoo\service\model.py", line 137, in retrying
    result = func()
             ^^^^^^
  File "C:\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 1921, in _serve_ir_http
    response = self.dispatcher.dispatch(rule.endpoint, args)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 2168, in dispatch
    result = self.request.registry['ir.http']._dispatch(endpoint)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_http.py", line 329, in _dispatch
    result = endpoint(**request.params)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 727, in route_wrapper
    result = endpoint(self, *args, **params_ok)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\odoo\addons\web\controllers\dataset.py", line 40, in call_button
    action = call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\odoo\odoo\api.py", line 517, in call_kw
    result = getattr(recs, name)(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\odoo\venv\Lib\site-packages\decorator.py", line 232, in fun
    return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 75, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 477, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(self.env.registry[self._name].button_install)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 601, in _button_immediate_function
    registry = modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\odoo\venv\Lib\site-packages\decorator.py", line 232, in fun
    return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\odoo\odoo\tools\func.py", line 97, in locked
    return func(inst, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\odoo\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 131, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "C:\odoo\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 479, in load_modules
    processed_modules += load_marked_modules(env, graph,
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\odoo\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 363, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\odoo\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 226, in load_module_graph
    load_data(env, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package)
  File "C:\odoo\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 70, in load_data
    tools.convert_file(env, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind)
  File "C:\odoo\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 608, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(env, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate)
  File "C:\odoo\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 679, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot())
  File "C:\odoo\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 594, in parse
    self._tag_root(de)
  File "C:\odoo\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 537, in _tag_root
    f(rec)
  File "C:\odoo\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 550, in _tag_root
    raise ParseError('while parsing %s:%s, somewhere inside\n%s' % (
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing file:/c:/odoo/modules/clientes/views/templates.xml:4, somewhere inside
<record id="clientes_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">clientes.tree.view</field>
        <field name="model">clientes.pc_clientess</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
          <tree>
            <field name="xempgen_id"/>
            <field name="xcliente_id"/>
          </tree>
        </field>
      </record>

The above server error caused the following client error:
RPC_ERROR: Odoo Server Error
    RPC_ERROR
        at makeErrorFromResponse (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/c24f766/web.assets_web.min.js:3061:163)
        at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/c24f766/web.assets_web.min.js:3066:13)

I don't know what to do, I was following a guide and tried it a couple of months ago and it did just worked, but now it's giving me this error that I'm not able to solve, thanks in advance guys.

First, you have an error in your xml: the modelname pc_clientess should have just one 's' at the end

Your error-traceback indicates: ValueError: Wrong value for ir.ui.view.type: 'tree'
in odoo version 18 (and above): tree is replaced by list
